# How to redirect web request to some page with NOT condition in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, regular-expressions

I want to redirect all requests for NOT(main.php) to handelrequest.php?page=[page]
So it must be something like:

```
RewriteRule !(main.php) handlerequest.php?page=$1
```

or

```
RedirectMatch !(main.php) handlerequest.php?page=$1
```

but it seems, that those modules haven't negation at all...

May be it is possible to combine it. Some thing like:

```
RewriteRule (main.php\?.*) $1
RewriteRule (*) handlerequest.php?page=$1
```

If not main.php, else for all others the second rule become active.
Is there some solution?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !main.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handlerequest.php?page=$1
```

That says.. if the requested filename is main.php don't run the rule.. for everything else run the rule.

Comment: It is also possible to add $ to !main.php to be more exact.